# Dynamic array and void pointers

Tags: c++, new-operator, void

I have quite peculiar problem. I want initialize an array pointed by a void pointer to which memory is allocated using new as shown below.

```
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
void InitArray()
{
    int *ptrInt = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for(int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
    {
         ptrInt[i] = 1; //OK
    }

    void *ptrVoid = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for(int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
    {
         *(int*)ptrVoid[i] = 1; //Culprit  : I get a compiler error here 
                                //(error C2036: 'void *' : unknown size)
    }
}
```

Now, I want to initialize the elements of this array which is pointed by `ptrVoid` with say 1. How do I go about it? With this code I get a compiler error as shown in the code(I am using VS 2010). Any suggestions?

Comment: don't use `new[]`. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Why do it all at once in the expression? Just get yourself a new intptr, and assign it the value of your voidptr. There are no extra points for the most cryptic code!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an order of operations problem (and an extra `*`).  Try this inside your second loop:

```
((int *)ptrVoid)[i] = 1;
```

Comment: @Chris - yes it is.  The `[]` array index operator occurs first - that's where the error comes from.  The fact that he has an extra dereference is also an error, but not the one causing the compiler message.

Answer (score 2):

`*(int*)ptrVoid[i]` is `*((int*)(ptrVoid[i]))`, and you're dereferencing too many times (the `[]` does a dereference).

Write `((int*)ptrVoid)[i]` (or, better, `static_cast<int*>(ptrVoid)[i]`) then re-consider your use of `void*` at all.

Comment: I wish I could avoid using void pointer but its use was necessary as I don't know what type of data I will have store using that pointer before hand and I don't want to use templates as it was slowing down the speed. I am using it in a very low level function which is called zillion  times to read data from  file.

Comment: @user672160: Templates do not affect execution speed. They are a compile-time construct *only*. Also, speed cannot be slowed down or sped up: an object has a speed that can be decreased or increased, making the object slow down or speed up, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to parenthesize correctly and cast the `void*` to an `int*`, so that the compiler knows how many bytes to offset when you index it with `[i]`.

```
for(int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
{
     ((int*)ptrVoid)[i] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int* ptrVoidAsInt = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
for(int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
{
     ptrVoidAsInt[i] = 1;                               
}
void* ptrVoid = ptrVoidAsInt;
```

But, one has to wonder what the meaning of either a void array or `1` initialised data is. Is this really an array of int or some other type that is going to be passed as a void* and then recast back to a typed array?